# Request & response handling in java

Tags: java, request

Servlets are one way of handling requests/responses from a web client i.e. a client makes a request, server finds the appropriate servlet which can handle the request and generate the response which is then forwarded to the client.
Could someone please tell me ways of handling requests/responses other than Servlets. I know CGI is another option, what else can be used?

Answer (score 0):

CGI is a poor choice for implementing HTTP protocol on the server-side. You can write the server manually (by opening a `ServetSocket`, parsing HTTP reauest headers and responding according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), however this approach is very tedious and error-prone.

If you want to handle web client requests, servlets are basically the only reasonable choice. Of course there are **tons** of wrapping technologies and frameworks (web, SOAP, REST, AJAX...)